# SQL occurrences of combinations into a matrix

Tags: sql, oracle

This seems like a rather common thing to do/query, but I'm not sure what is the best way to approach this and I cannot find similar examples. Basically I have 5 different systems where I've extracted the unique user IDs from the user log table. I want to know the overlap of users across the systems. The resulting tables are like this (user IDs are shared between systems):

```
sysA
-----
user1
user2
user3

sysB
-----
user2
user3
user4
user5

sysC
-----
user5
```

Now the output should be like this:

```
sysA sysB sysC sysD sysE count_distinct(userkey)
1    0    0    0    0    1
1    1    0    0    0    2
1    0    1    0    0    0
etc.
```

I tried doing this by using GROUP BY CUBE, which is something specific to Oracle and seemed useful in this case, but I couldn't get it to work as it seems I need to join every possible combination first in order to get the right result. Another thing I tried is this:

```
SELECT sysA_flag, sysB_flag, sysC_flag, sysD_flag, sysE_flag, COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT userId, 1 sysA_flag
  FROM sysA_input_table
) sysA
FULL OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT userId, 1 sysB_flag
  FROM sysB_input_table
) sysB
ON sysA.userId = sysB.userId
FULL OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT userId, 1 sysC_flag
  FROM sysC_input_table
) sysC
ON sysA.userId = sysC.userId
FULL OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT userId, 1 sysD_flag
  FROM sysD_input_table
) sysD
ON sysA.userId = sysD.userId
FULL OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT userId, 1 sysE_flag
  FROM sysE_input_table
) sysE
ON sysA.userId = sysE.userId

GROUP BY (sysA_flag, sysB_flag, sysC_flag, sysD_flag, sysE_flag)
```

In principle this gives the right output, but doesn't give all combinations (only for sysA). It might work by expanding on this, but it seems like an inefficient way to do it.

How should this be done in a proper way?

Comment: What do the rows represent - systems or users or something else? And what are the numbers in the matrix - whether some combination exists, or how may times, etc.? I can't see how your example data could be represented in the output you've shown. Are `sysa` etc. separate single-column tables? And what is the final column?

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes, sys* are separate single-column tables with (distinct) user IDs. The rows in the matrix represent all possible combinations of systems and the final column contains the number of user IDs which are all present in that particular combination of systems. User2 is in both sysA and sysB, and so is user3, which comes down to a total of two for that combination.

Comment: Mmm... OK... I think. But why is the count for the first row 1 rather than 3 - there are three user IDs in `sysa` (on its own or combined with itself)?

Comment: Also - are you only looking at pairs of systems, or all combinations - so the final row would be `1 1 1 1 1` (and count zero, presumably)?

Comment: @AlexPoole The first row of the matrix is 1 because there's one ID (user1) that's unique to sysA and doesn't occur in the other systems. user2 and user3 are shared between sysA and sysB and are represented in the next line ````1 1 0 0 0````. The final row only counts the user IDs that appear in all 5 systems, so while the figure would probably be low, it's not zero by definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The straightforward way should be something like this to start with. Answering the "how to do it" part of your question.

```
with sysA as (
select 'user1' as user_id from dual union all
select 'user2' from dual union all
select 'user3' from dual 
  ),
sysB as 
(
select 'user2' from dual union all
select 'user3' from dual union all
select 'user4' from dual union all
select 'user5' from dual 
  ),
sysC as
(
select 'user5' from dual
  ), cte as (
  select * from (
  select t1.*,'a' sys from sysa t1
  union all
  select t1.*,'b' from sysb t1
  union all
  select t1.*,'c' from sysc t1
  ) x
  pivot (count(*) for sys in ('a' as a,'b' as b,'c' as c))
  ),
  combinations as (select * from (select level-1 as a from dual connect by level <= 2) t1
cross join (select level-1 as b from dual connect by level <= 2) t2
cross join (select level-1 as c from dual connect by level <= 2) t3 
)
  select t1.a,t1.b,t1.c,count(t2.user_id) as user_count
  from combinations t1
left join cte t2 on t1.a = t2.a and t1.b = t2.b and t1.c = t2.c
group by t1.a,t1.b,t1.c
--having t1.a + t1.b + t1.c = 2
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_9EYyxdC)

Comment: I've looked at your suggestion and it seems to be working, however it does not include the single instances, so user IDs that are solely present in one system.

Comment: I forgot to comment the HAVING part in fiddle. Run it without it

Comment: Well I feel bad about not taking a proper look / fiddling around after running your query initially, because it's clear it does exactly what I want. Thanks a lot!